# Check substring key exists in word and return value

Tags: c#, data-structures

I'm trying to find the most time efficient way of classifying expenses on a piece of Accounting Software. The values come in like this:

```
"EFTPOS Kathmandu 2342342"
```

I have created a method as follows:

```
  private static string Classifier(string inputDescription)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> classified = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            classified.Add("D/C FROM", "INCOME" );
            classified.Add("CREDIT ATM", "INCOME");
            classified.Add("INTEREST", "INCOME");

        classified.Add("EFTPOS", "EXPENSE" );
        classified.Add("DEBIT DEBIT", "EXPENSE");
        classified.Add("CC DEBIT", "EXPENSE");

        classified.Add("PAYMENT RECEIVED", "TRANSFER");
        classified.Add("PAYMENT - THANK YOU", "TRANSFER");

        classified.Add("IRD", "TAX" );
        classified.Add("I.R.D", "TAX");

        try
        {
           // What do I do here to get the value?
            return value;

        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return "OTHER";
        }

    }
```

Basically, I want to run through the values of my inputDescription against the keys in the dictionary to get its value (the classification of the line item).

So for the example shown above, the result would be "EXPENSE".

I assumed dictionary would be the fastest way to approach this, but open to suggestions on better methods.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: String.Split(' ')? (`string[] words = phrase.Split(' ')`)

Comment: `string.Split` then a loop with `Dictionary.TryGetValue`.

Comment: @AsfK,, how would this work where I want to find phrases or substrings, like "D/C FROM", where using split string would make it "D/C" and "FROM", and therefore return null?

Comment: If you want that functionality then a `Dictionary` is not for you. You'll need to use a `List` instead and then loop through the entire list and check whether `inputDescription.Contains(individualEntryFromList)`.

Comment: @JayJ you say nothing about substring in your question.. anyway if you mean to two words you can search for the first word (let's say find in index i) now check the next one in i+1..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using RegEx?

```
const string EXPENSE_PATTERN = "^(EFTPOS|DEBIT DEBIT|CC DEBIT)"
const string ..._PATTERN

if (Regex.IsMatch(input, EXPENSE_PATTERN)){
    return "EXPENSE";
} else if (Regex.IsMatch(input, INCOME_PATTERN)){
    return "INCOME";
} else if (Regex.IsMatch(input, ..._PATTERN)){
    return "...";
} else {
    return "OTHER"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to achieve this is

```
string input = "EFTPOS Kathmandu 2342342";
string value = string.Empty;

foreach (var key in input.Split(' '))
{
   value = classified.Where(k => classified.ContainsKey(k.Key)).Select(k => classified[k.Key]).FirstOrDefault();

   if(value != null & value.trim()!= string.empty)
        break;
}
```

Check the `value` is null or not for further use. foreach loop will break once will find value.

Answer (score 0):

Calling method:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Classifier("EFTPOS Kathmandu 2342342"));
        Console.WriteLine(Classifier("D/C FROM Kathmandu 2342342"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Classifier method:

```
    private static string Classifier(string inputDescription)
    {
        var classified = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "D/C FROM", "INCOME" },
            { "CREDIT ATM", "INCOME" },
            { "INTEREST", "INCOME" },
            { "EFTPOS", "EXPENSE" },
            { "DEBIT DEBIT", "EXPENSE" },
            { "CC DEBIT", "EXPENSE" },
            { "PAYMENT RECEIVED", "TRANSFER" },
            { "PAYMENT - THANK YOU", "TRANSFER" },
            { "IRD", "TAX" },
            { "I.R.D", "TAX" }
        };

        try
        {
            foreach (var kvp in classified)
                if (inputDescription.StartsWith(kvp.Key))
                    return kvp.Value;

            return "OTHER";
        }
        catch
        {
            return "OTHER";
        }
    }
```

Returns:

```
EXPENSE
INCOME
```

Of course you could move the Dictionary definition outside of the method and make it a class member. That would especially make sense if you have multiple frequent calls to `Classifier`. You could also define it as an `IReadOnlyDictionary` to prevent changes to its contents.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get something from a dictionary is by using the key like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> classified = new Dictionary<string, string>();

var value = classified[key];
```

but of-course you would wanna check for the key occurence in dictionary like:

```
if(classified.ContainsKey(key))
     return classified[key];
else
         throw new InvalidTypeException();//this is because you should have all the key's mapped i.e you are only expecting known key types.People prefer other types like they would return null but i throw coz my dictionary is not having this key
```

Now coming to the values:

All the Values seem to be known and repeated types.So i would build an enum:

```
enum TransactionType
{
Expense,
Income,
Transfer
}

enum Source
{
EFTPOS,
DEBIT DEBIT,
...so on...
}
   i prefer enums to avoid magic strings and people do make mistakes while typing strings.
```

So with the Combination of Dictionary and enum now i would build as :

```
private Dictionary<Source,TransactionType> PopulateSource()
{
Dictionary<Source,TransactionType> classified = new Dictionary<Source,TransactionType>();
//populate dictionary by iterating using
 var keys = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Source)); 
 var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TransactionType));
you can just iterate through keys if your keys and values in enum are in order .

return classified ;
}

public void TestSourceTransaction()
{
TransactionType transType;
var classifieds = PopulateSource();
var key  = GetSourceType(inputDescription);//you need to write a method to get key from desc based on regex or string split options.
if(classifieds.ContainsKey(key))
          classifieds[key].Value;
else
         throw new InvalidTypeException("Source type undefined");
}
```

I prefer clean and expandable code and absolute no to magic string.

Comment: Well, OK. You can have enums for that also :)